# VM9878:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I have a probleme with my script. But, this problem one time appear, and one time not, without modification of the code.

My HTML :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="security();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></button>
    </span>
    <input id="inhuman" type="text" class="form-control" name="inputhuman" onblur="verificationSecurity();">
    <span id="humanerror" class="w39 input-group-addon"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <button id="send-mail" class="btn btn-primary pull-right w100" onclick="validation();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

My Javascript :

```
function securityCode() {

    [... MAKING THE SECURITY CODE ...]

    document.getElementById('inhuman').placeholder = secCode;
}

function verificationSecurity() {
    var secCode = document.getElementById('inhuman').placeholder;
    var secResult = document.getElementById('inhuman').value;
    var code = eval(secCode);

    if(code == secResult) {
        document.getElementById('humanerror').className = 'input-group-addon form-ok';
        document.getElementById('humanerror').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('humanerror').className = 'input-group-addon form-error';
        document.getElementById('humanerror').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        return false;
    }
}

function validation() {
    [... SOME OTHERS TESTS OK ...]
    var securityOK = verificationSecurity(document.getElementById('inhuman'));

    if(nameOK && emailOK && objectOK && messageOK && securityOK) {
        alert('ONLY FOR TESTS - OK');
    } else {
        alert('ONLY FOR TESTS - NOT OK');
    }
}
```

When i test the form, some time i have problem and some time all is OK. When it's not OK, i have problem on these lines (Chrome Dev Console) :

- var code = eval(secCode); > in function verificationSecurity()
- var securityOK = verificationSecurity(document.getElementById('inhuman')); > in function validation()

Sorry for my broken english and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's no `placeholder` in the `inhuman` element.

Comment: What's in the string you're evaluating?

Comment: The problem is with your use of `eval()`. It is not clear why you are using that.

Comment: Doing security verification in the client is just wrong. All the user has to do is open up Developer Tools to see the security code.

Comment: Sorry, the code is not complete.

A function called securityCode write the placeholder when the page is load. I edit the code.

Comment: What is the value of `secCode`? Since you're using `eval`, it needs to be valid Javascript code. The error indicates that it isn't.

Comment: Why would you use the placeholder for this, anyway? That's shown to the user before they edit the input field. Is this supposed to be like a CAPTCHA?

Comment: Btw, your `verificationSecurity()` function has no parameters declared but nonetheless you're trying to pass it a DOM element.

Comment: secCode is just a string same as 2 x 2 or 9 + 6. Yes, it's like a captcha. In the placeholder, the user see the string and enter in the input the result of the asked calcul.

the eval(secCode) evaluate a mathematical expression and after a test verify if the user input and the result of eval() are same.

Comment: The strangest thing is : on time i test the script and all is OK, all working fine. I reload the page and i test 2, 3, or 4 times and no problem. And (why?) i test a new time and i have this error...

Comment: OK. I have change the script with the return of an PHP function. Now, work fine. Thank for your responses.